# libcurl ssl support on macosx

Tags: python, macos, libcurl, pycurl

Please, can someone help me to enable SSL support for libcurl on my Mac - MacOSX High Sierra?

I am trying to run a script in Canopy that uses `pycurl`, but I get the following:

```
error: (1, 'Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl')
```

I tried re-installing curl with homebrew, re-installing `--with-nghttp2`, and re-installing curl and pycurl in Canopy, but I still get this error.

Comment: `--with-nghttp2` is for HTTP2 support, has nothing to do with SSL.  Do you have `openssl` installed via homebrew?

Comment: Hi - yes, opensll installed via homebrew. I tried the nghttp2 option based on a similar question asked, but for Ubuntu, where the suggestion was to do so and add --http2 in the curl command followed by the https:// url - but regardless of what I try, I keep getting the SSL error for libcurl.

Comment: I think the issue is with Canopy - I have to install curl and pycurl as a package inside Canopy, else the python script errors out on the import statement. Command line python curl to https now works fine, but not from within Canopy.